# All of sudden Silenium crawler stops

Tags: java, selenium

Can anyone please give me a clue, each time when the silenium crawler runs, after an hour of crawling, all of sudden the page gets redirected to the main page and crawler stops, but I put try and catch. I think, some kind of anti crawler stuff is being implemented on webpage, but not sure, how to identify it.

```
try {
            for(int s=0;s<pagesURL.size();s++) {
                searchWa(pagesURL.get(s));
            }
            printToConsole();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            if(e instanceof TimeoutException){
                System.out.println("Timed out: " + e);
                e.printStackTrace( );
            }
            else if(e instanceof UnhandledAlertException){
                System.out.println("Strange error: " + e);
                e.printStackTrace( );
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Error: " + e);
                e.printStackTrace( );}
        }
```

Comment: Selenium Crawler through Java sounds interesting !!!

Comment: There is one sophisticated approach, that is I need to log out and login in the middle of whole crawling process, but I would love to get experienced advice

Comment: I hope you won't mind guiding me to crawl through Java :) Thanks

Comment: If it's exactly one hour, then I suspect the session expires. You might want to keep checking the cookies and their expiration, and renew them accordingly (by logging in again would be the easiest I guess, and visit the last URL to continue where you left off). If this is the case, just track the expiration with `manager.getCookies()`.

Comment: @skandigraun Can you please give me more detailed information, how should I work with these cookies?

Comment: To confirm that this is the case, I would suggest to wait until the crawling stops again, and refresh the page manually, and check if you are still logged in. If you are logged out, then it's session issue. `driver.manage().getCookies()` will return a list of all cookies, `getCookieNamed(String)` will give you a specific cookie (you will need to know the name of the session cookie eventually). Then using cookie.getExpiry() should return a date, after which you will have to log in again. Or you can just simply set up some timer to log in once every hour without checking cookies.

Comment: @Sean Let me know if you are looking for a solution based on renewing the cookies. I can consider to construct an answer for you. Thanks